# How/Why do I get the following error:

Tags: python, ssh, server, paramiko

```
import paramiko

paramiko.util.log_to_file('ssh.log') # sets up logging
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect( 'ip_address', username='username', password='password' )
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls -l')
```

##Here is my error message

NameError: global name '_AES' is not defined

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please shown the full traceback message.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sdnousai\Desktop\SubJobServer.py", line 57, in <module>
    client.connect( 'IP_Address', username=username, password='password' )
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 266, in connect
    t.start_client()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 423, in start_client
    raise e
NameError: global name '_AES' is not defined

Comment: Can you include the callstack into the question, so it is readable? Use "edit" link.